# How to use multiple global ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider implementations at a time?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor, structuremap, mvcsitemapprovider

I'm trying to port the following StructureMap code from the MvcSiteMapProvider official documentation to Castle Windsor.

```
// Visibility Providers

// Explicitly set the visibility providers, using CompositeSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider to combine the AclModuleVisibilityProvider
// with all other ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider implementations.
this.For<ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProviderStrategy>().Use<SiteMapNodeVisibilityProviderStrategy>()
    .EnumerableOf<ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider>().Contains(x =>
        {
            x.Type<CompositeSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider>()
                .Ctor<string>("instanceName").Is("filteredAndTrimmedAndCustom")
                .EnumerableOf<ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider>().Contains(y =>
                    {
                        // Note that the visibility providers are executed in
                        // the order specified here, but execution stops when
                        // the first visibility provider returns false.
                        y.Type<FilteredSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider>();
                        y.Type<TrimEmptyGroupingNodesVisibilityProvider>();
                        y.Type<CustomVisibilityProvider>();
                    });
        })
    .Ctor<string>("defaultProviderName").Is("filteredAndTrimmedAndCustom");
```

Here is my code for Castle Windsor:

```
// Visibility Providers
container.Register(
  Component.For<ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider>()
    .Named("filteredAndTrimmedAndCustom")
    .ImplementedBy<CompositeSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider>()
    .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue(
        "instanceName",
        "filteredAndTrimmedAndCustom"))
    .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponentCollection(
        typeof(FilteredSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider),
        typeof(TrimEmptyGroupingNodesVisibilityProvider),
        typeof(CustomVisibilityProvider))));
container.Register(
  Component.For<ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProviderStrategy>()
    .ImplementedBy<SiteMapNodeVisibilityProviderStrategy>()
    .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue(
        "defaultProviderName",
        "filteredAndTrimmedAndCustom")));
```

The problem is that all my implementations of `ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider` are used globally after this code. If I have a local visibility provider named ``ABCVisibilityProvider` it will also be used globally. This line does not seem to be working like it should:

```
.DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponentCollection(
    typeof(FilteredSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider),
    typeof(TrimEmptyGroupingNodesVisibilityProvider),
    typeof(CustomVisibilityProvider))));
```

Did I not port the code properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not using the right method overload for `OnComponentCollection`. The constructor for `CompositeSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider` has a parameter named `siteMapNodeVisibilityProviders`.

```
.DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponentCollection(
    "siteMapNodeVisibilityProviders",
    typeof(FilteredSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider),
    typeof(TrimEmptyGroupingNodesVisibilityProvider), 
    typeof(PropertyTypeGlobalNodeVisibilityProvider)))
```